# SlowCheetah not transforming for Debug Configuration

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, app-config, slowcheetah

I have this issue whereby SlowCheetah works fine for all configuration types (Release, Staging, etc) except Debug.

I have a solution with a web project, where I'm transforming app.config files. I have various publish profiles, and can verify that they all work for any configuration except Debug.  When I publish using Debug, it copies the original config file, as well as the individual transform files.

I can recreate this using the following:
 - File System Publish
 - Web Deploy Publish
 - MS Build command line
 - MS Build via TeamCity

So it seems it's not specific to my machine as via Team City (running on another machine), the issue is the same.

Does anybody know of any configs anywhere that could be messing up my Debug configuration?

I guess a workaround could be to create a new configuration and publish using that instead, but that's just messy.  Interested in any other suggestions.

Thanks heaps
Greg

Comment: Wow... nobody has anything to contribute?  How dissappointing :(